# Wave accessibility tool is showing alert for Justified text

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wave

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc5hc.png)

```css
div.icons {                    
                    margin-left: auto; 
                    margin-right: 20%;
                    text-align: justify;
                    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
                    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
                    width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="icons">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="scan the QR code" src="~/Content/images/icon-QR.png" /></a>
                    <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-eap/id436292883?mt=8&ls=1" target="_blank"><img src="~/Content/images/icon-app-store.png" alt="Apple appstore"/></a>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onetapsolutions.morneau.activity&hl=en" target="_blank"><img src="~/Content/images/icon-google.png" alt="Google playstore"/></a>
                    <a href="https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/43853/" target="_blank"><img src="~/Content/images/icon-bb.png" alt="BlackBerry world"/></a>
                    <span class="stretch"></span>
                </div>
```

Wave accessibility tool is showing alert for justifying text. What should I do to get rid of this alert message?

Comment: An "alert" in the WAVE tool is just a "best practice" type thing. It is **not** an error or failure of WCAG (unless you're trying to achieve AAA conformance).

Answer (score 0):

## Do not justify text. Never.

[F88: Failure of Success Criterion 1.4.8 due to using text that is justified (aligned to both the left and the right margins)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F88.html)

Comment: @Adam. That may disadvantage people with good sight! See my answer.

Comment: note that wcag 1.4.8 is a AAA standard but most companies (and most laws) require AA, so 1.4.8 might not be required.

Answer (score -1):

Colin Wheildon did [some research](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1875750223) a while back to assess the effects upon comprehension with different typographical elements. Among many useful stats, was that with justified text, [normal sighted] readers would have almost twice the good comprehension rate compared with using ragged-right (67% vs 38%). Note that ragged-left only achieved 10%.

The justification [pun intended] for justified text not being compliant is that some people with limited visiblility can see 'rivers of white' in the text'. Autistic people also tend to be put off by the extra spaces, but also by words split by hyphenation and lines too close together which most do not have a problem with.

I am wondering if the research for that was done when displays did not microjustify text well, and did indeed leave almost double spaces, which tended to coagulate towards the centre of columns. This is not usually the case today, especially with portable devices with high resolutions that smoothly space words and render fonts and serif details very well. Colin's research was done with print media, where dpis were effectively into the 1000s, and continued into the digital age with the Linotype 1200 and 2400.

[F88: Failure of Success Criterion 1.4.8 due to using text that is justified (aligned to both the left and the right margins)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F88.html) used to say that you could provide justified text, but if you did, you should provide a readily identifiable means of turning it off. Now it says 'The best way to avoid this problem is not to create text layout that is fully justified', which is discriminatory and imposes a reading burden on most (even if they don't think so). WCAG is now being discriminatory. It is like enforcing all people to use long ramps instead of the quicker stairs.

A possible way to cater for both is to:

1. Include a css class to change justified text to ragged left (or right if dir=rtl), to be added to the body tag. It could also increase the line spacing, remove hyphenation and underline all links.
2. Include a link on every page that links to the same page but with a GET variable appended to the URL.
3. When the GET variable is detected by the page rendering software (say PHP or XSL), it adds the special class to the `<body>` tag, and appends the GET variable to each link, so that every page from then on is also ragged.

Note that to be compliant, you need to also examine use of css `::before` and `::after` pseudo-classes to ensure that they don't contain any non-decorative (that is, important) content that accessibility software will not pick up. A typical place for using these may be for custom lists, especially if trying to cater for more than the limited number of languages that html supports in lists.

This is a case where choosing a one-size-fits all approach disadvantages a large number of readers. It is like getting everyone to use long ramps rather than stairs. Not catering for those with difficulties is not fair, but so is making it more difficult for the majority in order to cater for a relatively small minority. This is a zero-sum situation, where choosing one solution creates problems for others, with those advocating for it pretending that others don't have issues with their so-called solution, which is what was done to people who they are now purporting to represent. The better approach is to offer an alternate reading mode that is maintained across a site.

I know that ragged-right is used extensively on the web, along with sans-serif text, which has worse ratios for good comprehension compared with serif (12% vs 67%). Using both of these poorer choices for computing were valid when rendering of serif fonts and spacing was poor, but displays can now render at near to the resolutions used for quality printing, where full justification and serif fonts have been used for well over a century, because they worked best. Every major newspaper uses them, in print. Note that the early monochrome green or amber computer displays were fed with text with monospaced serif fonts, though that may have had to do with not having excessive spacing between letters.